# c++: Coping to an stl container that is passed by reference

Tags: c++, stl, copy, containers

Using the following code:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    void GetStrings(list<std::string>& strs)
    {
        strs = m_strings;
    }   

    list<std::string> m_strings;
}
```

Are all `m_strings`'s elements being copied when `strs = m_strings;` is performed?

In other words:
Is this equal to `list<std::string>& strs = m_strings;` or to `list<std::string> strs = m_strings;` (with respect to elements copy)

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/operator%3D

Comment: Of course the elements are copied. What else could possibly happen?

Comment: @KerrekSB, I thought perhaps when doing `MC.GetStrings(strs)` then `strs` will be a reference to `MC.m_strings`.

Comment: @Subway: That's not how references work. You should really have started with a much simpler piece of code like `int n = 10; int & a = n; a = 20;` to make sure you understand how references work.

Comment: @KerrekSB, Thanks. I'm going to study it right away, could you please  suggest me some good web references?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.

Now, if you wanted to copy just a reference to the list (like you have in languages such as C# or Java) then pass a shared_ptr instead, then you will have a single list with 2 references to it.

All variable assignment in C/C++ is done by value, even if the variable being passed is a pointer (eg a 4 byte variable). Other languages are the same, its just that they cover this up with their language constructs.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a special reason that you are advised using a shared_ptr, not a raw pointer, in this context?

Comment: raw pointers require more care, they're easy to use if you are on top of what your code is doing, but often people don't (I blame these easy to use languages :) ) so a shared_ptr gives you both the ref counting safety and the raw pointer functionality, so its not a bad thing to use by default. YMMV of course.

Comment: @Subway Most likely you do **not** want a shared pointer. You only use that if you want shared ownership semantics, which isn't clear in your case.